# TestFlight Testing low Framerates?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, testflight

I am trying to upload my game to the app store (it is currently on the google play store) but since I use a pc, I had to borrow a mac from a friend to publish my game.

I built the game on my pc, uploaded it to my dropbox and downloaded it onto the mac. I then finished the game on Xcode and used testflight to test my game.

However, the game is running at about 20-30 frames approx, not 60. The low frames are clearly visible and it affects with the gameplay.

I was wondering if this has to do with testflight or if I built it wrong, or if I did some settings wrong on Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% that the Xcode/build problem, the test flight does not touch your code in any way.

Comment: Do you know what I need to fix to improve the frame rates?

Comment: it may do a very little with settings on Xcode. Most likely it's a unity export settings problems. I would advise you to look for the web for similar questions, because that behaviour may occur for a variety of reasons.